# Python: if a value in a column equals any value in another column, turn both values to zero

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I was hoping I could receive some help on thinking through a python problem.  I have a General Ledger of Data, and would like to delete, or turn to zero, any accrual.  All this means is, I want to find one number in a column, and search for it in another column.  If i find a match, I want to turn both numbers (the iterable number, and the found number) to zero.

I know I need to use some form of an iterable like the following:

```
for x in df[column 1]:
    if x is in df[column 2]:
        x == 0
        df[column 2 [index?]] == 0
    else:
        continue
```

Could someone assist me in writing the correct code to accomplish this?  My goal is two essentially iterate through two columns, find where two values match, and turn those values to 0.  Thank you.

Comment: is it guaranteed that elements in the columns are unique? If not, what should behavior be when there are multiple matches?

Comment: it will be very rare that two floats, to the hundredth decimal, will match.  The risk of matching something that should not be matched is low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use enumerate to get the index in order to set the value in the list to zero:

```
for i, x in enumerate(df[col1]):
    matches = [j for j, y in enumerate(df[col2].isin([x])) if y is True]
    if len(matches) == 0: continue
    df[col1][i] = 0
    k = matches[0]
    df[col2][k] = 0
```

If an element in df[col1] appears in df[col2] multiple times, this will only set the first occurrence to 0.

If you want to remove all occurrences, you could use this code:

```
for i, x in enumerate(df[col1]):
    matches = [j for j, y in enumerate(df[col2].isin([x])) if y is True]
    if len(matches) == 0: continue
    df[col1][i] = 0
    for k in matches:
        df[col2][k] = 0
```

Comment: The first code has an error with the .index(x) i believe....wont let me run it in jupyter.  The second code however, works pretty well....I used a dummy data set with two columns and put some numbers that equal in different rows.  It worked for every single instance.  Thank you for your help so far - very very helpful.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of lists, not dataframes. Let me update

Comment: @Ryan updated and both codes work now (tested locally)

Comment: This has helped tremendously. Thank you.

Comment: @Ryan Glad to hear. If it solved your problem, please accept the answer so that its marked as resolved.

Comment: I have marked it as solved.  One last thing if you could drop some knowledge - how does k = matches[0] work? i see that its different from removing all occurrences in your second code.  This has worked exactly as it should.

Comment: Matches is a list containing the indices/row numbers of all matches in the second column. Print it out to see for yourself! Setting k=matches[0] sets k equal to the first element in that list, the first match in col2.

Comment: ah okay, and then it kind of inherently loops through the entire list until there are no more matches?

Comment: The outer loop (“for i, x in enumerate”) loops through the elements of the first column. For each element (“i, x”) you then check the entire second column if that appears. All indices where that element from col1 appears in col2 are stored in matches. k is the first of thise indices. Update the value of col1 at i, of col2 at k!

Comment: :) thank you. You saved me 6-7 hours of manual excel work and I am appreciative of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `any`:

```
list = ["one", "two", "three"]
foo = ["bannana", "apple", "two", "blue"]

o = []
for x in foo:
    if any(n in x for n in list):
        o.append(0)
    else:
        o.append(x)
print(o)
```

which iterates through `foo` and appends zero to the output list if a match is found in `list` else returns the value if no match is found:

```
['bannana', 'apple', 0, 'blue']
```

## Update:

Actually, this answers your question better than my previous - using list comprehension:

```
foo = [[1, 2, 3, 5], [9, 7, 2, 4]]
for x in foo[1]:
    if x in foo[0]:
        foo[0] = [0 if i == x else i for i in foo[0]]
        foo[1] = [0 if i == x else i for i in foo[1]]
print(foo)
```

The `foo[0]` is the list with the items to be checked for and `foo[1]` are the items to be checked against. This outputs `[[1, 0, 3, 5], [9, 7, 0, 4]]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
idx = np.flatnonzero(df['col1'] == df['col2'])
df['col1'][idx] = 0
df['col2'][idx] = 0
```

Instead of exact equal you can test for approximate equality using [`numpy.allclose()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html):

```
idx = np.flatnonzero(np.allclose(df['col1'], df['col2']))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `isin`

```
df[column 1] = df[column 1] * (~df[column 1].isin(df[column 2])
df[column 2] = df[column 2] * (~df[column 2].isin(df[column 1])
```